# how to set the dockable window default location for notepad++

Tags: c#, plugins, notepad++, scintilla

How do I set the dockable window default location in a scintilla document by writing plugins for notepad++ in c#. I tried the following code:
  NppTbData.Mask = NppTbMsg.DWS_DF_CONT_BOTTOM

Help me to do the same..